# Overwriting a plist file with content of a NSMutableArray (first item is always NULL in plist)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

- I am trying to use plist files to save a list of items from a text
  file from a web site. When I first create the plist file and add
  items to that, there is no problem. But when I try to remove an item
  from plist, it is not removing the index, it only overwrites the
  content of this index with NULL. And I tried an other way; I tried to
  create a new array without the item I want to remove, and overwrite
  plist file with the content of this new array. In this way, the item
  I wanted to remove is removed, but surprisingly the first item gets
  NULL! A more surprising situation is, I also write it to a new plist
  file with same technique, and it is perferct! This is a very
  primitive code, unfortunately it didn't worked for me. I searched
  plenty of tutorials, but I couldn't overcome. How can I write the
  content of a string array to a plist file without extra null objects
  and without loosing datas?

========================================================================

I composed a sample code below :

```
- (IBAction)logFromPlist{

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data2.plist"]];

    NSLog(@"LOG:");
    NSLog(@"arrplist count : %d", [arr count]);
    for(int a=0; a<[arr count]; a++){
        NSLog(@"*** %@", [arr objectAtIndex:a]);
    }
}

- (IBAction)logFromPlist2{

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data3.plist"]];

    NSLog(@"LOG:");
    NSLog(@"arrplist count : %d", [arr count]);
    for(int a=0; a<[arr count]; a++){
        NSLog(@"*** %@", [arr objectAtIndex:a]);
    }
}

- (IBAction)addValue{

    NSString *deger = [field5 text];  //New value text field in IB
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data2.plist"]];
    if(arr == NULL){
        arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [arr addObject:deger];
    [arr writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data2.plist"] atomically:NO];
}

- (IBAction)removeFromPlist{

    NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data2.plist"]];

    if(arr2 != NULL){
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *key = [field8 text];

        for(int i = 0; i < [arr2 count]; i++){
            NSString *cntStr = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] stringValue];
            if(![cntStr isEqualToString:key]){
                NSString *tempDeger = [arr2 objectAtIndex:i];
                if(tempDeger != NULL){
                    [arr addObject:tempDeger];
                }else{
                    NSLog(@"it is NULL");
                }
            }
        }

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data2.plist"] error:nil];   //I tried this line by removing next line

        [arr writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data2.plist"] atomically:NO];   //It is writing the array to plist but first item is always null

        [arr writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data3.plist"] atomically:NO];   //same technique but everything is ok in this plist


        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data3.plist"] toPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data2.plist"] error:nil];   // trying to copy correct plist file (data3.plist) to original plist file (plist2), but it does not fix the problem.

    }
}
```

Project file : http://www.ozgunbursalioglu.com/files/plistWork.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least your `copyItemAtPath:` will always fail since it won't overwrite files (data2.plist already exists).

Comment: But before I deleted the file data2.plist by this command: [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data2.plist"] error:nil];

Comment: Really?? In your code I see you first delete data2, then write to data2, then write to data3, then try to copy data3 to data2.

Comment: Sorry, my lack of explanation. I mean, I tried to remove the line: [arr writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/data2.plist"] atomically:NO];   so first write it to data3.plist, then try to create data2.plist, but the result is same.

Comment: How do you check that first item is null? Try to open your plist files with Xcode to see what's actually written there.

Comment: I tried two ways. First I logged the NSHomeDirectory when running it on simulator. Then I opened the plist files with text editor. I had entered 5 values, in the plist file first item is <string></string> The other ones are filled. Second way, I jailbreaked my ipad and browse the Documents directory of my application with iFunBox. There is same situation with first way.

Comment: I uploaded the project to my host. If you want to see it you can download from here : http://www.ozgunbursalioglu.com/files/plistWork.zip

Comment: `<string></string>` isn't a NULL value! It's just an empty string (arrays actually can't contain NULLs at all).

Comment: Yes arrays can not contain NULL objects, I am already controlled the array before I write it to plist and there was no problem at that array. Example: The array contains value1, value2, value3, value4. When I write it to data2.plist, in plist file it is like that : <string></string><string>value2</string><string>value3</string><string>value4</string>

Comment: you can add `NSLog(@"%@",arr)` before `[arr writeToFile: ...]` line and `NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: ...]` after it to be completely sure.

Comment: It is very interesting, I just tried your advise and in both two logs everything seems ok. But after that program crashed. In the plist files everything seems ok too. I have to write a line NSLog() to work properly? It is very funny :) I am trying to solve the carsh now, may be it can be the reason. Then I'll reply you again...

Comment: It is really really funny that, when I add line : [NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: ...] after [arr writeToFile:..] then problem is fixing. But when I remove this line, again same problem is appearing. I think this is a very important bug. I trust the commands to save my data, but it is loosing them for only the reason of not writing an NSLog() line after that!! Anyway thank you very much mifki for your big help...

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your file by setting the automatically to YES

```
 [arr writeToFile:PATH atomically:YES];
```

And also try to check the BOOL value returned to see if your oerration done  successfully

Comment: I control the plist files, it writes datas, remove datas, but problem is loosing first item when recreating the data2.plist file, it gets NULL.